# name 'Player' is not defined and <module> game = Game()

Tags: python, pygame

I'm watching a tutorial to program a game in python. On the tuto everything goes well but my program generates errors. However, I did exactly as on the tutorial. I tried to find the error by myself thanks to the error message but I can't find a solution so I turn to you to find a solution to my problem. So, I have 3 .py files in my project (main.py, player.py and game.py) and a .tmx file. The errors are in the files 'main.py' and 'game.py'. (PS: this is the first time I use StackOverflow).
Thanks to all in advance.

The title is not very relevant I think, so sorry.

The errors :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC0q0.png)

main.py :

```
import pygame

from game import Game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

game.py :

```
import pygame
import pytmx
import pyscroll

class Game:

def __init__(self):
    # fenetre du jeu
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))  # taille de la fenetre
    pygame.display.set_caption("Pygamon - By BenCorp")  # nom de la fenetre

    #charger la carte (tmx)
    tmx_data = pytmx.util_pygame.load_pygame('map.tmx')
    map_data = pyscroll.data.TiledMapData(tmx_data)
    map_layer = pyscroll.orthographic.BufferedRenderer(map_data, self.screen.get_size())
    #map_layer.zoom = 2

    #generer le joueur
    self.player = Player()

    #dessiner le groupe de calques
    self.group = pyscroll.PyscrollGroup(map_layer=map_layer, default_layer=1)
    self.group.add(self.player)

def run(self):
    # boucle du jeu
    running = True

    while running:

        self.group.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

    pygame.quit()
```

player.py :

```
import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load('player.png')
    self.image = self.get_image(0, 0)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

def get_imaged(self, x, y):
    image = pygame.Surface([32, 32])
    image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0, 0), (x, y, 32, 32))
    return image
```

Comment: `import player` in _game.py_ and `self.player = player.Player()`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You must import the module `player` in *game.py*:

```py
import player
```

So you can use the class `Player` from the module `player`:

```py
self.player = player.Player()
```